# How to capture response after calling REST API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to call REST API as

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getoutput()
{
  var client = new RestClient("....");
  var request = new RestRequest(".....");
  
  var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
  return Ok(response.Content);
}
```

My response is like

```
{
  "number" : 567889
}
```

I want to get that number 567889 and save it into variable in my controller. But I am not able to do so.

I tried with

```
var answer = response.Content;
```

But it is showing the JSON.

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: The [documentation describes how to deal with response](https://restsharp.dev/intro.html#response), including how to deserialize the response to an object. Did you refer to the documentation? Try to implement deserializing to a specific type? Have you declared a type that matches the shape of the JSON you're getting back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a class for your data

```
public class Answer
{
public int number {get;set;}
}
```

and action

```
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
Answer answer= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Answer>(response.Content);

int number=answer.number;

  return Ok(answer);
```

or if for some reason you don't want to create a class, you can parse a json string

```
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

int _number= (int) JObject.Parse(response.Content)["number"]

  return Ok( new { number= _number} );
```

Comment: Is there any other method also if I don't want to create a class ?